# AWS External SAML IdP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, saml, idp

Im currently facing an issue, with SAML IdP and roles in AWS.
I have Account A, where I have a SAML Provider.
Then i have Account B, where i have my Role, that has a trust policy towards the SAML Provider in Account A.

*Constraints: The SAML Provider in Account A can not be setup in Account B*

When I then tries to assume the role, with a generated SAML by my application and by using assume-role-with-saml with the SAML, I get the following:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the AssumeRoleWithSAML operation: Principal exists outside the account of the Role being assumed
```

The thing is, that I dont see any where in the documentation, that a SAML Provider needs to be in the same account as the role it is giving access to.

One quirky workarround would be to have a role in Account A with the trust to the SAML Provider, and the let the role in Account B trust that, in order for it to be assumable.

Wondering if anyothers have a better solution for this?